# Issue with PDO Connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am new to this so dont be rude :D

I have 3 file: database.php, init.php and user.php

Here the init.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

require 'database.php';
require 'functions/user.php';
$errors = array();
```

Here the database.php:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "xxxx";
$db_user = "xxxx";
$db_pw = "xxxx";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user,  $db_pw);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

And here the user.php:

```
<?php
function userExists($user) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($results) > 0) return true;
        return false;
}
```

So the error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /mnt/web109/b2/35/57848035/htdocs/includes/functions/user.php on line 4 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /mnt/web109/b2/35/57848035/htdocs/includes/functions/user.php on line 4
```

The function userExists() is called in another file named login.php. In login.php i have already required init.php. The error message appears when i want to login.

So i hope you can help me.

Thx

Comment: Start with understanding variables' scope.

Comment: I thought that is enough to require databse.php and user.php in ini.php.. I saw this in a video few days ago and there it works so i tried it now and get errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$conn` is not available in your function since it is in a different scope. Pass it as a parameter or declare it as a global variable.

```
function userExists($user, $conn){
    // ...
}
```

or

```
function userExists($user){
    global $conn;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As a side note, using "global" is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

In your `userExists` function you are calling `$conn` variable which isn't global scope ([Give a small look here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php))..

You can use one of these:

```
function userExists($user, $conn){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($results) > 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

OR

```
function userExists($user){
    global $conn; //<--- bad practi
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($results) > 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

OR
   use of `$GLOBALS` variable

```
function userExists($user){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($results) > 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `$GLOBALS[$conn]` should be `$GLOBALS['conn']`

Comment: @Reebal your welcome ! !  joconja Thanks Sir for correction